# C++ Vector.erase() causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I have a C++ vector and it has some blank elements in it. I wanted to remove any empty string elements from the vector. I tried this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < myvector.size();i++) {
  if (myvector[i] == "") {
    myvector.erase(myvector.begin()+i);
  }
}
```

When I run this code I get a segmentation fault. Is there something wrong with it? Or does this code work for any of you?

Comment: Your real problem of logic is of course that you are incrementing `i` when you shouldn't.

Comment: There's nothing in this code that would cause a segfault out of nowhere. (Of course it fails to actually erase all the empty items).  You must have some other issue in your program (e.g. earlier heap corruption, or the objects in your vector don't have correct value semiantics).

Comment: Once STL's [uniform container erasure](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4009.txt) makes it into the standard, we'll be able to say `std::erase_each_if(myvector, std::mem_fn(&std::string::empty));`...

Comment: @KerrekSB, Cool, didn't know that was a thing. I have a function for it already, but still.

Comment: @chris: Of course, *everyone* already has a function for this -- that's why it's something considered for standardization ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that you want the usual remove-erase idiom:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

myvector.erase(std::remove_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(),
                              std::mem_fn(&std::string::empty)),
               myvector.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have for example vec=["A","","B","C"] and you're delete the element a[1], now 'vec' is long 3 not 4, so vec[3] causes segmentation fault.

Try this:

```
for (vector<...>::iterator i=myvector.begin(); 
              i != myvector.end(); /* do nothing here */) {
   if (i->empty()) {
      i=myvector.erase(i);
   } else {
     ++i;
   }
}
```

However Kerrek's solution is more elegant.

Comment: Your iterator is becoming invalidated. And `myvector[i]` isn't valid. (And `interator` lol)

Comment: @FedericoReghenzani Thanks for your answer too. I couldn't get it to work at first but now it does.

Comment: 1) const-iterators suffice; 2) `*i == ""` looks clumsy, why not `i->empty()`?

Comment: If you're wondering about the segfault, compare it to [this one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d60993335cb274a4).

Comment: @chris I've just edited with the same correction :) Thank you for all comments and sorry for mistakes

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm sorry for my English (I'm Brazilian and I'm using the Google translator). But your problem is not exclusively about deleting an item outside the vector, but about accessing its element. Think about the following situation: I have a vector v = {1, 4, 2} and I want to exclude all even numbers using a for and an iterator. When the iterator arrives at the second element (v [2]) it will exclude 4, making the vector {1,2}. But before leaving the for loop, the iterator is still pointing to the second element (v [2]), which is the last element. When it exits, the iterator will be incremented (i ++) and will be equal to v.end (). Therefore, even if it does not give a segmentation fault, the algorithm will not remove all even numbers and, if v was equal to {1,3,4}, it would give the segmentation fault. To fix this, right when you use v.erase (), use i-- (which in the case of your code, which does not directly use the iterator, will work in the same way).Or you can use an increment condition, as in the previous answer, but the iterator needs to be updated correctly.